# Testing for constant mean (stationarity)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, mean, image-processing

I have a grayscale digital image with noise and I would like to test for uniformity in small neighborhoods.

One hypothesis says that the mean is independent of the spatial coordinates, against the hypothesis that the mean does significantly depend on them.

I don't know how to formalize that problem and formulate the test, can you help ?

The mean and the variance are unknown. If necessary, the distribution of noise can be assumed Gaussian with constant variance. If also necessary, a non-constant model can be assumed planar.

Note that I am looking for an isotropic method, so splitting the neighborhood in two and comparing the means is not the best option.

Comment: Local stationarity?

Comment: @user2974951: I am unsure of the proper term, but probably yes, though the dependency would be spatial rather then temporal.

Comment: There are some posts on this subject, see [Tests for spatial stationarity (homogeneity)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57357/tests-for-spatial-stationarity-homogeneity)

Comment: @user2974951: thanks. the link is not very substantial, but I'll retain the idea that "Nonstationarity may well be evident by fitting a model and then assessing the fit".